# Сотрудничество с Российским Красным Крестом

Tags: кавычки

Нужно ли брать название организации в кавычки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не нужно. Красный Крест в кавычки не берется. Например, Международное Движение Красного Креста и Красного Полумесяца.